# Double inheritance type deduction

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have the following template class:

```
template<class T>
class Foo {
  public:
    void Bar(T* t) { member = t; }
  private:
    T* member;
};
```

This is used (twice) as a base class for a different class:

```
class AwesomeClass : public Foo<ISomeInterface>, public Foo<IOtherInterface> {};
```

Which is then called something like this:

```
class Caller {
  void Init(ISomeInterface * i) {
    AwesomeClass a;
    a.Bar(i);
   }
}
```

However this does not compile, stating that the call to Bar is ambiguous. Therefore I need to use `a.Foo<ISomeInterface>::Bar(i)`, because apparently the compiler cannot determine which Bar to call (even thought it is given an ISomeInterface object). Any ways around this?

Also I am wondering if inheritance is the 'correct' approach here or if composition would be a better option.

Comment: It is opinion based, of course, but in my opinion you should stick to composition. The only reason to use inheritance is when you want to implement functionalities, i.e. implement an interface. But this doesn't seem the case here.

Comment: @freakish Inheritance needs to die: https://boxbase.org/entries/2020/aug/3/case-against-oop/

Comment: @Dai make that class inheritance... interface (abstract baseclass) inheritance is still useful for dependency injection/unit testing (the implementation of these interfaces should be done with aggregation) polymorphism too). And yes theoretically this could be done in C++ with concepts and static polymorphism too (instead of an interface there will be a concept requiring a set of interface method signatures).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can introduce `Bar`s into `AwesomeClass`, then both can be found in scope of `AwesomeClass` then overload resolution kicks in. E.g.

```
class AwesomeClass : public Foo<ISomeInterface>, public Foo<IOtherInterface> {
public:
    using Foo<ISomeInterface>::Bar;
    using Foo<IOtherInterface>::Bar;
};
```

[LIVE](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/4Yn6oG3PP)

Comment: This seems to work but I am wondering why it is necessary. Is there a good reason why it couldn't work without this? I am failing to see what extra information the compiler has.

Answer (score 1):

You want friend functions and [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl). This way you don't need to individually `using` every such method from every base.

```
template <typename T>
class Foo
{
    T *member = nullptr;
    
  public:
    friend void Bar(Foo &self, T *t)
    {
        self.member = t;
    }
};
```

```
void Init(ISomeInterface * i)
{
    AwesomeClass a;
    Bar(a, i);
}
```